CSS loaded but changes not taking effect
So basically I have a server.js file running on a 2012 server that serves my static HTML, CSS, and JS files from a public subfolder. The original CSS I wrote works for the page as needed as well as the html and the JS (including the API). For some reason when I make a basic change just to see if a change is actually taking place like setting the background-color: red; in my #body{yada yada}, nothing happens. I have tried ctrl+f5 and I have tried ctrl+c on the 2012 server command prompt to restart the node server. This seems so simple a problem for a project that is 80% done.
     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Timecard</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="body">
            <nav class="navbar">
                <a href="http://ip placeholder/">
                    <img src="./company.png" alt="Company Logo" class="logo">
                </a>
            
                <div id="date"></div>
                <div class="links">
                    <a href="/timecard-manager">Time Card Manager</a>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div id="maincontent1">
                <div id="alphabetLinks"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="grid-item" style="font-weight: bolder; font-size: large; 
    text-align: center;">EMPLOYEE</div>
                    <div class="grid-item" style="font-weight: bolder; font-size: large; 
    text-align: center;">TODAY'S ATTENDANCE</div>
                <div class="grid-item" style="font-weight: bolder; font-size: large; text- 
   align: center;">SUMMARY</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="grid-item" id="employeeList">Employees will be listed here... 
     </div>
                <div class="grid-item">Item 5 with text.</div>
                <div class="grid-item">Item 6 with a lot of text to see how it expands. 
    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br></br>
        <div id="maincontent3">
            <table>
                <tr id="tr3">
                    <td colspan="3">
                        <label id="clocktext" for="employee">Clock:</label>
                        <select name="employee" id="employee">
                          <option value="In">In</option>
                          <option value="Out">Out</option>
                          <option value="Personal">Personal</option>
                          <option value="Lunch in">Lunch in</option>
                          <option value="Lunch out">Lunch out</option>
                        </select>   
                        <br>
                        <label for="memo">Memo:</label>
                        <input id="memo" placeholder="Memo"><br>
                        <label for="password">Password:</label>
                        <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="button">ENTER</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        </div>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
        <br>
        <p>new content added here</p>
    </body>
    </html>


In your developer tools (F12) -> Network tab, can you confirm your css is loaded, and it is the right version? There is also a little checkbox "Disable cache" which you can try. Maybe it helps =)
